# ERROR: Error cloning remote repo origin Jenkins hosted inside Docker

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

For a latest Jenkin hosted inside docker on windows 10, I am unable to do a git pull...

I created a test project using public repository on Github to build docker image.

[image]

Here is the error I am seeing in console. Not sure what's wrong here.

```
Started by user Administrator
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on Win_10_192.168.1.90 (windows) in workspace d:\Jenkinsbuilds\workspace\Git HelloWorld
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/karthequian/docker-helloworld.git
 > git init d:\Jenkinsbuilds\workspace\Git HelloWorld # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init d:\Jenkinsbuilds\workspace\Git HelloWorld
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:957)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:737)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 172.17.0.1/172.17.0.1:48788
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1788)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:998)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1122)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)
        at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1880)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: git init d:\Jenkinsbuilds\workspace\Git HelloWorld
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2379)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2298)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1857)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:955)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "d:\Jenkinsbuilds\workspace\Git HelloWorld"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:936)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:454)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2365)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my Git configuration in Global Tool Configuration

[image]

And Git is already installed on Windows 10 system where the build should happen.
[image]

Git is also installed on the container.
[image]

What could be wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by adding Git path into Global Tools Configuration.

[image]